# Gradle extremely slow HTTP resource access on Windows. How to diagnose and fix?

Tags: windows, performance, http, gradle

Gradle 2.2 takes hours to build a project on a PC that takes 8 minutes on Linux. When run with –debug, on the slow machine, gradle reports no errors, but it stops and waits for approx. 2 minutes at every resource, after every User-Agent line:

```
18:39:15.819 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: Gradle/2.0 (Windows 7;6.1;amd64) (Oracle Corporation;1.7.0_67;24.65-b04)
<2 min. delay>
18:41:15.527 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
18:41:15.527 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Linux workstations on the same subnet (behind the same firewall and using the same squid proxy) do not have this delay.

[An Extended snip from Windows is here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73Gfrx7fEx1X1RjT01DcjNmcnM/view?usp=sharing)

[Snip from Linux build around same point in build.](https://gist.github.com/Charlweed/60f03c2888eac82fb9e3)

Comment: Can you provide the same log for the linux side? And can you try this on the Windows side to see if you see the same hang: `$ curl -v -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" -A "Gradle/2.0 (Windows 7;6.1;amd64) (Oracle Corporation;1.7.0_67;24.65-b04)" http://repo1.maven.org/maven
2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/3.5.200-v20140224-1527/preferences-3.5.200-v20140224-1527.jar.sha1`

Comment: `curl.exe -v -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" -A "Gradle/2.0 (Windows 7;6.1;amd64) (Oracle Corporation;1.7.0_67;24.65-b04)" http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/1.2-SNAPSHOT/ForgeGradle-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Has no delay. It goes right to a 404 error.

Comment: [The log from cURL.](https://gist.github.com/Charlweed/d70722728bc5e972f767)
Same request in gradle waits for 2 min!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a VERY STRANGE issue with a transparent  http proxy and DansGuardian web filter. For still unknown reasons, this one PC’s http traffic got mangled.
This is odd, because our entire LAN’s http traffic to the internet is content filtered. There was a filtering exception that allowed any traffic from this slow pc to be unfiltered. But that had the opposite effect as expected. Gradle traffic became crazy slow on the ‘unfiltered’ PC, while content-filtered workstations had no problems. Even stranger, Gradle also ran at normal speed on unfiltered Linux workstations.

The workaround was to configure IPTables and the transparent proxy to completely ignore the slow pc's http traffic. So now it is unfiltered, and unproxied. It has been nicknamed the pornstation.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to us as well, though in our case it was caused by the AntiVirus on the PC ([Nod32](http://www.eset.com/) not to name it).
We had to completely disable the HTTP/web filters on it.

May not be your case, but may help others coming here for advice.